# Weird caption fonts for table and figures

Tags: texstudio

I am using Elsevier(Journal) latex template that has packages installed as shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

% If the frontmatter runs over more than one page
% use the longmktitle option.

%\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % imported from old paper
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{automata, chains, positioning, arrows}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage[caption=false]{subfigure}
%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
```

The problem is that the caption text fonts for figures and tables are displayed strangely totally different from document text font as shown below. Any idea how this issue can be solved, I am using texstudio:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add an example of how you input the code for the figure?

Comment: \begin{figure}[t!]
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figs/stdma-phases.png}
 \caption{Initialization, Network Entry and First Frame Phases in STDMA Protocol}    
 \label{fig:stdmaPhases}
\end{figure}

Comment: i am using double-column template

Comment: `\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}` do you really mean that? it makes float pages more or less impossible

Comment: don't add code in comments please fix the example in the question so that it is a an example of the problm you are asking about (you can use `example-image` as the image, i is available for tests.

Comment: This is the default for the `cas-dc` document class. It sets `table` and `figure` `\caption`s using `\sffamily` and `\small`. Is this for an article submission? If so, leave things as they are. If not, a rudimentary way of changing it would be to remove the functionality of `\sffamily` and `\small` as part of the `align` key-value provided by the class for `figure`s and `table`s. So, `\begin{figure}[align=\let\sffamily\relax\let\small\relax\raggedright]` and likewise for a `table`.